# Bounding Riemann zeta function by Euler product formula for finite $N$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-zeta, bernoulli-numbers

In [a paper concerning a quick calculation of Bernoulli numbers](http://modular.math.washington.edu/projects/168/kevin_mcgown/bernproj.pdf) the following inequality is presented (page 3), only referring to it as "not hard to see" that it holds.

$$ \sum_{n \leq N}^{} n^{-s} \leq \prod_{p \leq N}^{} (1 - p^{-s})^{-1}$$

where $p \in \mathbb{P}$.

I believe it is not too hard to see, but I guess I miss some elementary background. Could someone explain how to derive this inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Try $N=4$ and expand and multiply the two  geometric series on the right.

Comment: Doing so much linear algebra and vector calculus almost made me forget about geometric series lol. Thanks, I recognize it now and then the result is indeed trivial.